# Custom Settings access through system mode?

Tags: apex, visualforce, customsetting

I am unable edit the the custom settings in VF page.
Since the access was not given in customize application. So I wrote a controller and ran in system mode. But still i am unable to edit the custom settings record.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do Internal User manages Custom Setting data without 'Customize Application' Permission?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76974/how-do-internal-user-manages-custom-setting-data-without-customize-application)

Comment: @RahulSharma While his class isn't set for `with sharing`, I think you're correct that he needs to explicitly set it to `without sharing` to see if that solves his issue as per sfdcfox's answer to your linked question.

Comment: @crmprogdev Once I had an issue in remoting method, otherwise I used to think a class runs in without sharing mode unless we write with sharing. So have learnt that explicitly writing without sharing is not same as not writing with sharing.

Comment: @RahulSharma That's correct. There is indeed a difference between the two. `without sharing` if called from a `with sharing` class is still `without sharing` while the other is not.

Comment: @crmprogdev Ah you're right, but I had only just single controller and page which were exposed to sites. Was not able to access data without explicitly writing `without sharing`

Comment: @shyam, try writing without sharing in your class- `public without sharing class Rforce_PDQSettings_CLS`